# How to Retrieve the height and width of an Image after it is resized for a View

Tags: javascript, selenium

How to Retrieve the height and width of an Image after it is resized for a View. I have an image which could have a original height and width but as per the needs user can resize the image size

Eg: From the console, this code renders the client height :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("WiderImage")[0].clientHeight
```

Help me to get the value and store to validate using selenium.

I tried the following - But it returned null

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver; 

String x =(String) js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('imageWiderThanText')[0].clientHeight;");

long client_height = (Long) js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('imageWiderThanText')[0].clientHeight");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is good. You just need to use "return" in executeScript to get the value :

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('imageWiderThanText')[0].clientHeight;");
```